# React: Callback not being counted as called in Jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, callback, fetch-api

I have simplified my code for example purposes, but still do not understand why the Jest test is failing.

The component is a button that, when clicked, it makes an API fetch, then makes a prop callback call.

In the test, I get the button and click it. The test counts the fetch call. But when I check the callback, the test fails.
Can not figure why. TIA

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import jest from 'jest-mock';

const ClickTarget = ({ onSuccess }) => {
  async function handleClick() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/posts/');
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    onSuccess('Done');
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleClick()} data-testid="saveBtn" type="button">
      Save
    </button>
  );
};

// JEST TEST
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({ "content": "test" })
);

console.log = () => { };

describe("ClickTarget component", () => {

  it("should call API then callback", () => {
    const mockSuccessCb = jest.fn();

    render(<ClickTarget onSuccess={mockSuccessCb} />);

    const btn = screen.getByTestId('saveBtn');
    expect(btn).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(btn)
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toContain("/api/posts/");

    // test fails HERE onSuccess called after fetch not recognized
    expect(mockSuccessCb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockSuccessCb.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('Done');

  });
});
```

Comment: Extra context, I am using Node v20.9.0

Comment: "jest": "^29.3.1",

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to make the check wait because the fetch call is an async it throws off the timing.
Changed the test to be **async** and then use **waitFor** with a timeout

```
it("should Save content on submit", async () => {

...

await waitFor(()=> expect(mockSuccessCb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1), {timeout: 1000});
```